# 2021 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

[Moderator election #1](https://alcohol.stackexchange.com/election/1) on Beer, Wine & Spirits has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and the new moderator is:

[image: Ken Graham]

They will be joining [the existing crew](https://alcohol.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly — please thank them for volunteering and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://alcohol.stackexchange.com/election/1) or [view a summary report online](https://www.opavote.com/results/6287883137712128).

Answer (score 4):

Well done Ken - well deserved. Happy to see you as mod here.

Comment: Thank you, Rory. It was an honour to run along side such a good challenger as yourself. Congratulations on becoming a moderator on Travel SE!

Answer (score 4):

I wish to thank all who took time to vote in this election. A warm thank you goes out especially to Rory who ran as a candidate for being a moderator.

May this be a great occasion that I may serve this community in a way that it may be well built up and grow continuously.